# Any way to search in all files of a directory and subdirectory using python regex?

Tags: python, regex, bash

I have following python regex to search all endpoints and urls in a file.

```
regex_str = r"""
  (?:"|')                               # Start newline delimiter
  (
    ((?:[a-zA-Z]{1,10}://|//)           # Match a scheme [a-Z]*1-10 or //
    [^"'/]{1,}\.                        # Match a domainname (any character + dot)
    [a-zA-Z]{2,}[^"']{0,})              # The domainextension and/or path
    |
    ((?:/|\.\./|\./)                    # Start with /,../,./
    [^"'><,;| *()(%%$^/\\\[\]]          # Next character can't be...
    [^"'><,;|()]{1,})                   # Rest of the characters can't be
    |
    ([a-zA-Z0-9_\-/]{1,}/               # Relative endpoint with /
    [a-zA-Z0-9_\-/]{1,}                 # Resource name
    \.(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,4}|action)          # Rest + extension (length 1-4 or action)
    (?:[\?|/][^"|']{0,}|))              # ? mark with parameters
    |
    ([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,}                 # filename
    \.(?:php|asp|aspx|jsp|json|
         action|html|js|txt|xml)             # . + extension
    (?:\?[^"|']{0,}|))                  # ? mark with parameters
  )
  (?:"|')                               # End newline delimiter
"""
```

I only know  how to use this regex to search for single file but I want to use this regex to search endpoints & urls in a directory which have hundreds of files in many subdirectories.

In bash we can simply use `grep -r "find_this"` to search in a directory , is there any way in python similar like bash to search in all files of a directory ? or can you help me to convert this python regex to bash regex ?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a short example file. Are you trying to search ALL files or just all with certain file extensions?

Comment: Also please show what the output should look like.